# A version of shortvrb for listings?

Tags: listings, verbatim

So, [`shortvrb`](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/macros/latex/unpacked/shortvrb.sty) is a neat little package that allows you to do `\MakeShortVerb{\|}` which then has `|foo|` behave like `\verb|foo|`.

Now, I like `listings`. Is there a `\MakeShortListings` that makes `|bar|` act like `\lstinline|bar|`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstMakeShortInline[basicstyle=\small\ttfamily]{|}

\begin{document}

foo |bar| baz

\lstDeleteShortInline{|}
foo |bar| baz
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define the character in question to be active and define it to `\lstinline[<options>]<char>` where `<char>` stands for the character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\catcode`|=\active
\def|{\lstinline[language=C]|}

\begin{document}

|\relax|


|int main();|

\end{document}
```

A `\MakeShortListings` based on this can be defined the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*\MakeShortListings[2][]{%
    \catcode`#2=\active
    \begingroup
    \def\@tempa{\lstinline[#1]}%
    \lccode`~=`#2%
    \lowercase{\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\def\expandafter~\expandafter{\@tempa~}}%
}

\MakeShortListings{\|}

\begin{document}

|\relax|

\MakeShortListings[language=C]{\|}

|int main();|

\end{document}
```

If you also want to be able to delete the special meaning of this char again, like `\DeleteShortVerb` allows it for `\MakeShortVerb`, you can use these to save and restore its catcode and definition. This already make the character active.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{shortvrb}

\newcommand*\MakeShortListings[2][]{%
    \MakeShortVerb{#2}%
    \begingroup
    \def\@tempa{\lstinline[#1]}%
    \lccode`~=`#2%
    \lowercase{\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\def\expandafter~\expandafter{\@tempa~}}%
}

\MakeShortListings{\"}

\begin{document}

"\relax"

\MakeShortListings[language=C]{\"}

"int main();"

\DeleteShortVerb{\"}

``test"


\end{document}
```

Comment: I've accepted Herbert's answer since it seems to be the "canonical" one. But I think I have learned something about catcodes from this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Seamus: Sure, no problem. Herbert's answer should be accepted. I didn't know that `listings` provides such a macro already. (There was however not much reason that it got down-voted by two people. The solution is sound IMHO.)

Comment: I hadn't noticed you'd got downvoted! That does seem harsh. Just because there's a "better" solution doesn't mean this isn't a good solution